# convert groovy JsonOutput to YamlOutput

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I need to convert groovy **JsonOutput to YamlOutput**, there's no groovy YamlOutput library,

https://github.com/apache/groovy/tree/master/subprojects/groovy-yaml/src/main/java/groovy/yaml

what's the other alternative I could do to make this happened?  The JsonOutput.java is about 300 lines.

The groovy yaml library got only Builder and Slurper (and other two).

Here's one of the example on the code to convert,

`JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(variable1))`

Or the main output of file or variable, create a class to convert json to yaml output?

Thanks
Ric

Comment: There's `groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder`  https://gist.github.com/kirklewis/e7dd2f9402679c4c36d4132d4f28b2ee

Comment: There's a https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-yaml/src/main/java/org/apache/groovy/yaml/util/YamlConverter.java how do you use this?  Can't find an example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot of course convert it line by line, you need to finish the json, and this works,
YamlConverter.convertJsonToYaml(jsonReaderVar);